# Visual Studio Express 2010 css file stops working after I edited while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual studio express 2010.  I downloaded it about 2 weeks ago.  I have been building Asp Net WEB Site (Razor.) I have a rather simple class in a css file being referenced from a helper file that is called from a content page.

All the styles in the css files were working as planned.  While using the debugger, I changed the colore value of the css class to what is shown bellow.  Visual studio does not seem to see the change.  I have gotten out of the debugger and tried to change it again.  When I enter debug again, The original (prior to the change made while debugging) styles are shown.  All other changes in the css file are being ignored as well.  I have tried to use alt F5 to enter the debug to clear browser.

This is the class that I changed in the debugger:

```
.NavMainButtonSelected
{
    background-color:Red;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-F5 (rather than Alt-F5) - This usually does a clean refresh. (Not sure which browser you're in).

Answer (score 1):

In the browser, try Control + F5. You can also set the browser to renew every single hit on the page (not a bad idea on a development machine).

Comment: Thankyou Tim, Gregory, and Slaks.  I appreciate your help with such a silly rookie mistake.  I am progressing again.  Thanks.  Mark

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+F5 **in the browser** to force it to ignore its cache.

Comment: This still happens. Even after F5 stoping the development server, clearing all cache/Temp folders and shutting down and restarting the machine. I had ctrl f5 work after several tries and I have had it not work after more the fifty tries with doing all of the above. This is a bug somewhere.