# Change image size in ASP, C# and CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, image, image-size

Why when I place the mouse on top of the image doesn't change its size?

I have this on a ASP webpage:

```
<asp:Image ID="ProdImage" CssClass="ImgDetail" runat="server" />
```

The Page_Load() loads the URL of the image like this:

```
ProdImage.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/Images/Products/" + lblProductID.Text + ".jpg");
```

The CSS ImgDetail class looks like this:

```
.ImgDetail
{
    width: 180px;
    height: auto; 
}

.ImgDetail:hover
{
    width: 360px;
    height: auto; 
}
```

I just want to change the image size when the mouse is on top of the image.

Thank you.

Comment: a few obligatory questions just to rule things out (since your code looks OK): Can you see the image on page load? Are you sure your CSS is loaded and not overwritten anywhere? If it's online, could you pass a link?

Comment: I have created a fiddle which you can check. It uses the same code as you do so the problem is not there. You should check the other suggestions I gave you. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kennethtruyers/Lr4kj/

Comment: Can you post code for rendered HTML please?

Answer (score 0):

First debugging step I'd take is confirm that ANY css style you're applying is working. So give .ImgDetail a 1px border red or something. If you don't see it on page load, it means your CSS file isn't being included, which is a common mistake.

Comment: Thanks Richthofen, I changed this line: '<div class="ImgDetail"><asp:Image ID="ProdImage" runat="server" /></div>' and I can see the picture to move but doesn't change its size.  May be because it is inside a table?  I will continue debugging it.

Comment: Pabinator, did you try my suggestion? if you assign in your CSS file a red border to the ImgDetail class, does the image show the red border?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of solved the problem thanks to @Richthofen idea.

I checked the local CSS file (`http://localhost:4290/Styles/Site.css`) during debugging and it didn't have my changes on it.

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't update the CSS file when I start its debuger (F5).  However, it updates the CSS file if I publish the webpage.

These are the properties of the CSS file on the Visual Studio 2010:

Build Action: Content

Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

Closing and opening VS 2010 didn't fix it.  I had to reboot my PC for the CSS file to have my changes on debugging.  I'm affraid I have to reboot my PC every time I need to debug the CSS file unless anyone knows how to fix this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: @Richthofen  I found a solution to this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510617/visual-studio-express-2010-css-file-stops-working-after-i-edited-while-debugging I had to do Cntrl + F5 on the IE Browser to take the CSS changes.  Thanks